# Is it possible to see if two Javascript objects that are printed on the console are the same instance (preferably in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I run the following code in Chrome I would like to see that `a` and `b` are referring to the same object but `c` is not. Is there a way?

```js
let a = {x:1,y:2,z:3};
let b = a;
let c = {x:1,y:2,z:3};

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "store as global variable" feature.

Right click on the `{x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}` text on each output, and click "Store as global variable". You will get 3 variables:

`temp1`, `temp2`, `temp3`.

And then, try these:

```
temp1 == temp2
// output true
temp2 == temp3
// output false
```

Tip: you can access any (even those in a very deep callback) variables in this way as long as you use the console to output them.

Comment: I did not try this b/c I was assuming that the browser would copy the object. So the global variable will always reference the actual object. Good to know.

Comment: Yes. If the browser copies the object, the debug tool will be a nightmare - you would never trace back what you're after.